# How to verify that the param data is not undefined in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Nodejs and Express. For updating data i have the following code

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {  
  const updatedUser = {
    username: req.body.username,
    age: req.body.age,
    dateOfBirth: req.body.dateOfBirth,
    occupation: req.body.occupation,
    businessName: req.body.businessName,
    joinDate: req.body.joinDate,
    familyMembers: req.body.familyMembers,
    isActiveMembership: req.body.isActiveMembership,
    membershipEnd: req.body.membershipEnd
  };

  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id,updatedUser);
};
```

The problem is , if the user does not pass any of the params, the `undefined` gets added to the database. I obviously don't want to be checking each params individually if it's undefined.

So, what would be a good way to handle this ?

Comment: Do you want to make all fields mandatory? or remove `undefined` ones

Comment: ignore undefined ones , so that they dont update in the DB

Comment: If you are using mongoose, show you model, pls! Make all fields are required in `User` model.

Comment: i don't want all the values to be required, they are optional. The user can update the previous values if needed.

Comment: you are showing `previous` values in your update form ?

Comment: Yes , I do. The client is supposed to send the previous data also , but need to make sure undefined is handled on server side

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over available property in `req.body` and set the poperties and values to be updated accordingly:

```
const updatedUser = Object.keys(req.body).map(el => {
  return { [el]: req.body[el] }
})
```

```js
const req = {
  body: {
    age: 2,
    name: 'hey',
    occupation: 'troll'
  }
}

const updatedUser = Object.keys(req.body).map(el => {
  return { [el]: req.body[el] }
});
console.log(updatedUser)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

So currently I am using the following approach.

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {  
  const updatedUser = {
    username: req.body.username,
    age: req.body.age,
    dateOfBirth: req.body.dateOfBirth,
    occupation: req.body.occupation,
    businessName: req.body.businessName,
    joinDate: req.body.joinDate,
    familyMembers: req.body.familyMembers,
    isActiveMembership: req.body.isActiveMembership,
    membershipEnd: req.body.membershipEnd
  };

  const filteredValue = _.pickBy(updatedUser,function(item){
    return item !== undefined;
  })

  //Save the filteredValue in the DB

};
```

*will keep the question open incase someone suggests a better approach.